# "Провести" с математическими действиями

Tags: глаголы

Можно ли с математическими действиями сочетать глагол "Провести"?

Провести умножение, деление, провесии действие.

Провести — это же обиходное "произвести".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно употребляются следующие выражения: *выполнить деление (математическое действие), произвести деление объектов на группы.*

Также можно сказать: *произвести деление многочлена на двучлен.*

В разговорной речи делается замена: *провести деление*, так как глагол ***провести*** может иметь значение "выполнить, совершить", но в словарной статье оно указано в самом конце, в то время как для глагола ***произвести*** это основное значение.

Из словаря:

ПРОИЗВЕСТИ,  св. 1. что. **Сделать, совершить;** провести. П. выстрел. П. вычисление. П. ремонт. П. обыск. П. расчёт кого-л.

ПРОВЕСТИ,  св. 1. кого-что. Ведя, сопровождая или направляя, помочь, дать возможность пройти, проехать. П. слепого через улицу. П. людей через болото. П. машину на стоянку.  7. **что. Осуществить, произвести, выполнить** (какие-л. действия, работу). П. репетицию.  Хорошо п. урок.  П. уборку урожая.

В чем же разница между этими глаголами? Вот интересная статья о глаголе ***производить***:

[ПРОИЗВОДИТЬ](https://gufo.me/dict/vinogradov/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%98%D0%97%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC)

Суть ее в том, что современное значение глагола производить (=выполнить, совершить) совсем недавнее. `Еще во времена Пушкина  глагол имел значение:  творить, из небытия в бытие **приводить, рождать.** Обратим внимание на вторую приставку ИЗ.

В 30—50-х годах XIX в. определились три значения этого глагола: 1) Сделать, изготовить, выработать; родить   2) **Осуществить, выполнить.** Произвести опыт, наблюдение, раскопки, исследование. 3)  Породить, вызвать, возбудить. Произвести впечатление;

И только в наше время значение "осуществить, выполнить" становится **основным.**

Answer (score 1):

Этот глагол не сочетается с *элементарными* действиями, которые не воспринимаются как *продолжительный во времени* процесс: если их нельзя "**вести**", то нельзя и "**провести**" (совершенный вид того же глагола). Трудно представить себе, как "*ведут*" умножение однозначных чисел (обычно берут ответ из памяти, в крайнем случае - из таблицы). Однако *в специфическом* контексте "проведение" математической операции возможно, как и всякое "*(про)ведение расчётов*", например:

> Ученик *провёл* деление двух пятизначных чисел "в столбик" [операцию, процедуру
>   деления] и получил правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В толковых словарях указано, что **произвести** [какие либо действия] является одним из значений слова **провести**. При этом никаких помет, указывающих на "обиходность" этого значения, нигде не ставят. [Пример](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&all=x).